# Can I rename "All apps" on Windows 10 start menu back to "Accessories"?

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, start-menu, acer-aspire, accessories

"All Apps" on the Start Menu is not an intuitive name for me, so I would like to change the text to "Accessories". Is there a way to do this using the windows registry, or some other means? My OS is Windows 10 Home, x64, and the laptop is an Acer Aspire E-15.

Comment: What do you intend to do with the _existing_ Windows Accessories item?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @LeoKing in Windows 7 and prior there's "Accessories" menu item in "All programs" which contains Windows tools, so renaming "All apps" to "Accessories" doesn't make sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't rename this button, this belong to Windows Core.

And by the way i think there is a lot of hierarchical paths that you have to change to make it work.

But you can make a folder inside your start menu and put your stuff in, then you can give it a name that makes you glad.

Comment: "You can't rename this button" Well, that's a shame. I guess you did answer the question, though.